# Sesiones con PHP con estructura MVC

Tags: php, mvc

**como puedo valirdar que exista la session en la funcion index? tambien necesitare validar la sesion en otras funciones que me renderizan otras vistas. la funcion index no me esta validando la session que ha sido creada en el login. asi como tengo el codigo no me permite renderizar la vista que estoy invocando en la funcion del index**

```
public function login(){
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
                $datos = [
                    'userName' =>trim($_POST['userName']),
                    'password' =>trim($_POST['password']),
                ];

                if(($this->requisitoModelo->login($datos))){
                    //Obtener credenciales del modelo
                    $credenciales = $this->requisitoModelo->login($datos);
                    $datos=[
                        'credenciales'=> $credenciales
                    ];
                    session_start();
                    //Asignando Valores a variables de Sesion 
                    foreach($datos['credenciales'] as $acceso):
                        $_SESSION['userName'] = $acceso->userName;
                        $_SESSION['idUnidad'] = $acceso->idUnidad;
                        $_SESSION['password'] = $acceso->password;
                    endforeach;
                    $userName = $_SESSION['userName'];
                    $idUnidad = $_SESSION['idUnidad'];
                    //$this->index($idUnidad); 
                    redireccionar('/paginas/index/'.$idUnidad);
                }else{
                    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Datos Incorrectos");window.location.href="http://localhost/requisitos/"</script>'; 
                }

            }else{
                $datos = [
                    'userName' =>'',
                    'password' =>''
                ];
                $this->vista('paginas/login',$datos);//cargar vista 
            } 
        }

public function index($idUnidad){
            if (session_status()===1){
                $this->vista('paginas/login');//cargar vista 
            }else{
                //Obtener los Requisitos
                $requisitos = $this->requisitoModelo->obtenerRequisitos($idUnidad);
                $datos = [
                    'requisitos'=> $requisitos
                ];
                //var_dump($_SESSION);
                $this->vista('paginas/inicio', $datos);            
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar el index y que el header te direcciones a las vistas que desea, lo que tienes que asegurarte que la url de la vista venga completa

```
public function index($idUnidad){
            if (session_status()===1 && $ideUnidad == "" ){
                header("Location:".'"'.$this->vista('paginas/login').'"')
            }else{
                //Obtener los Requisitos
                $requisitos = $this->requisitoModelo->obtenerRequisitos($idUnidad);
                $datos = [
                    'requisitos'=> $requisitos
                ];                
                header("Location:".'"'.$this->vista('paginas/inicio', $datos).'"');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola, me causa duda esta sintaxis `Location:$this->vista` si es correcta?

Comment: Saludos Location se encarga de direccionar, entonces $this->vista seria la url del sitio que quiere direccionar por ejemplo herder(Location: 'www.google.com') tu $this->vista seria la url ese sitio o pagina

Comment: Si a lo que voy es que me [parece](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) debe ir entre comillas

Comment: Si ya modifique y le coloque las comillas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

el problema que tengo es que cuando accedo por url por ejemplo a Localhost/requisitos/paginas/index/ sin haber iniciado sesion, no tendria que abrirme esa direccion porque no existe una sesion activa